# linear ODE with discontinuous nonhomogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

In *Boyce's Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems*(global edition, 2017) pp 264-5 it says that if $y$ is a solution of 2nd order ODE $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=g(t)$ where $p, q$ are continuous and $g$ is only piecewise continuous on an interval, $y$ and $y'$ are continuous on the interval but $y''$ has jump discontinuities at the same point as $g$. Furthermore it says the same about higher order linear ODEs. The book doesn't have any proof for this, so I would like to know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is not the basic case of an ODE where all the components are continuous functions. However, under the given assumptions the integration interval has a finite subdivision so that $g$ is continuous and bounded over each segment and thus has a solution there in the strong sense.

The question now is how to define a generalized solution over the full interval. The minimal condition is of course that the solution function be continuous. Next up that it has a continuous derivative. Now the jump discontinuities on the right side only have one place to occur also on the left side, and that is in $y''$.

One could also put this in another way, let $G$ be a continuous integral function of $g$. Then set $u(x)=y'(x)-G(x)$ so that then one obtains in $y,u$ the first order system
\begin{align}
y'&=u+G\\
u'&=y''-G'=-py'-qy\\
&=-p(u+G)-qy
\end{align}
This now satisfies the continuity assumptions for a linear system over the full integration interval. Again, in the result the jumps of $g$ are replicated as jumps in $y''$.

Comment: So in the second paragraph you are saying that 'If we assume that there is a solution(strong sense) $y$, by definition $y$ and $y'$ should be continuous and therefore $y''$ should have jump discontinuities to compensate for $g$'?

Comment: There is no solution in the strong sense as the equation over the full domain does not satisfy the assumptions for it. For a solution in a more general sense, you will lose properties of strong solutions. To preserve as much properties of a strong solution as possible, you start from the weakest, most general ones. Thus you would care about continuity of $y$ and $y'$ first, in contrast to starting with continuity for $y'$, $y''$ (which is possible, but would hardly be called a solution).

Comment: But I think that your third paragraph says there is a solution in the strong sense. That is, the existence of $y, u, y', u'$ is guaranteed throughout the interval and since $G'=g$ exists(though not continuous), $y''=u'+G'$ exists(though not continuous). Therefore we have that there is a twice-differentiable function $y$ that satisfies $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y= g(t)$ throughout the interval.

Comment: No, the third paragraph derives a coupled system for $(y,u)$ of first order, resulting in a continuously differentiable solution, in both components. Nothing there gives that $y$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: But $y' = u + G$ and because $u$ and $G$ are both differentiable, isn't $y'$ also differentiable?

Comment: $G$ is not continuously differentiable, its derivative has jumps.

Comment: To conclude, you mean that generally there is no solution(function $y$ satisfying the equation and of course having a second derivative over the full interval) because $g$ does not satisfy necessary assumptions, but if there exists one, it should satisfy the conditions you wrote($y, y'$ continuous but $y''$ isn't)?

Comment: Yes. One has to define what "solution" means in the more general context. The most natural ideas would be those that are compatible with the transformation in the third paragraph to a "standard" ODE system, or with sequences of continuous approximations on the right side (generalized by ideas of Fillippov for even more discontinuous equations), which both give exactly this $C^1$ continuity.